# Inventory of all files across tenant with permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I have been asked to pull a list of all documents in document libraries across various site collections in our tenant along with the permissions against those files.

My immediate thought is that this can be achieved via Powershell script though before I embark on that I wanted to check that I am not overlooking anything that may already be built into Office 365/SharePoint Online?